# Изменение значения QLabel в зависимости от выбора элементов в QComboBox и по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты

Я хочу когда у нас в `comboBox` выбран **`ТЕКСТ 1`**, на окне отображался бы **`ТЕКСТ 1 1`**, 
по нажатию на кнопку **`2`** текст, изменялся на **`ТЕКСТ 1 2`**, 
по нажатию на кнопку **`1`** текст менялся на **`ТЕКСТ 1 1`**.

Когда у нас в `comboBox` выбран **`ТЕКСТ 2`**, на окне отображался бы **`ТЕКСТ 2 3`**, 
по нажатию на кнопку **`4`** текст, изменялся на **`ТЕКСТ 2 4`**, 
по нажатию на кнопку **`3`** текст менялся на **`ТЕКСТ 2 3`**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Window1(object):
    def setupUi(self, Window1):
        Window1.resize(800, 450)
        self.Main1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Window1)
  
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.Main1)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(693, 0, 91, 22))
        self.comboBox.addItem('ТЕКСТ 1')
        self.comboBox.addItem('ТЕКСТ 2')

        self.comboBox.activated[str].connect(self.change_science)

        self.item = {'ТЕКСТ 1' : self.item_one(), 'ТЕКСТ 2' : self.item_two()}
        self.science_now = str(self.comboBox.currentText())
        self.change_science(self.science_now)

        Window1.setCentralWidget(self.Main1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Window1)


    def change_science(self, text):
        for i in self.item.get(self.science_now):
            i.setHidden(True)
        for i in self.item.get(text):
            i.setHidden(False)

        self.science_now = text

    def item_one(self):
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.Main1)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 50, 170, 22))
        self.label.setText('ТЕКСТ 1 1')

        self.pushButton_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Main1)
        self.pushButton_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 422, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton_1.setText('1')
        self.label.setHidden(True)

        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Main1)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(93, 422, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton_2.setText('2')
        self.label.setHidden(True)

        return [self.label, self.pushButton_1, self.pushButton_2]

    def item_two(self):
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.Main1)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 50, 170, 22))
        self.label.setText('ТЕКСТ 2 3')
        self.label.setHidden(True)

        self.pushButton_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Main1)
        self.pushButton_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 422, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton_1.setText('3')
        self.pushButton_1.setHidden(True)

        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Main1)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(93, 422, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton_2.setText('4')
        self.pushButton_2.setHidden(True)

        return [self.label, self.pushButton_1, self.pushButton_2]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Window1 = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Window1()
    ui.setupUi(Window1)
    Window1.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

НИКОГДА НЕ ИЗМЕНЯЙТЕ код, сгенерированный *Qt Designer*, НИКОГДА.

Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета, и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Window1(object):
    def setupUi(self, Window1):
        Window1.resize(800, 450)
        self.Main1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Window1)
  
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.Main1)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(693, 0, 91, 22))
        self.comboBox.addItem('ТЕКСТ 1')
        self.comboBox.addItem('ТЕКСТ 2')

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.Main1)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 50, 170, 22))
        self.label.setText('ТЕКСТ 1 1')

        self.pushButton_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Main1)
        self.pushButton_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 422, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton_1.setText('1')

        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.Main1)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(93, 422, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton_2.setText('2')

        Window1.setCentralWidget(self.Main1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Window1)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Window1):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
       
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.comboBox.activated[str].connect(self.change_science)
        
        self.pushButton_1.clicked.connect(self.clicked_button_1)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.clicked_button_2)
        
    def change_science(self, text):
        if text == 'ТЕКСТ 1':
            self.label.setText('ТЕКСТ 1 1')
            self.pushButton_1.setText('1')
            self.pushButton_2.setText('2')
        elif text == 'ТЕКСТ 2':
            self.label.setText('ТЕКСТ 2 3')        
            self.pushButton_1.setText('3')
            self.pushButton_2.setText('4')

    def clicked_button_1(self):
        if self.pushButton_1.text() == '1':
            self.label.setText('ТЕКСТ 1 1')        
        if self.pushButton_1.text() == '3':
            self.label.setText('ТЕКСТ 2 3')          
            
    def clicked_button_2(self):
        if self.pushButton_2.text() == '2':
            self.label.setText('ТЕКСТ 1 2')        
        if self.pushButton_2.text() == '4':
            self.label.setText('ТЕКСТ 2 4')          
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем использовать два класса это же можно сделать и с одним ?

Comment: @qwerty, файлы, сгенерированные pyuic, никогда не должны редактироваться. 
Эти файлы предназначены для использования исключительно в качестве импорта и 
всегда должны оставаться неизменными (подробнее об этом очень важном аспекте 
читайте в официальных рекомендациях по использованию Designer https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html